# BasicHttpBinding security on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8

I have a self-hosted WCF service with simple username / password validation. The "security" part of the code in the conosle app that hosts the service is:

```
BasicHttpBinding b = new BasicHttpBinding();
b.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
b.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
//add endpoint
selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISettings), b, "SettingsService");

//add creditential check
selfHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
selfHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new CustomValidator();
```

But i cant figure out what to do on my windows phone to use user / pass creditentials, this is what i have so far:

```
BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
httpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;

sc = new SettingsClient(httpBinding, new EndpointAddress("http://" + addressField.Text + "/IC/SettingsService"));
sc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
sc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test123";
```

This always returns a 401 error. Also i dont have any special configuration in my xml files.

Comment: is it hosted in IIS or in IIS Express/WebDev ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i figured this out, i had quite a few problems:

1. I was runing the self hosted service from another project but i had the App.configfile in the same project as my service. Didnt know it had to be in the same project where you run the service from, stupid of me.
2. I now have all the configuration in my xml file, but i could probably put it in code and it would still work.
3. Refer to this [LINK](http://cisforcoder.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/how-to-implement-basic-http-authentication-in-wcf-on-windows-phone-7/), it describes how to do the authentication on WP7 (works well with WP8).
4. Make sure you update your service reference when you change something in your service.

**Client code:**

```
private void Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        ServiceClient sc = new ServiceClient();
        using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(sc.InnerChannel)) {
            HttpRequestMessageProperty request = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            request.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + EncodeBasicAuthenticationCredentials("test", "test123");
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, request);
            sc.setPushUriAsync(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
            }

}

private string EncodeBasicAuthenticationCredentials(string username, string password) {
    string credentials = username + ":" + password;
    var asciiCredentials = (from c in credentials
                            select c <= 0x7f ? (byte)c : (byte)'?').ToArray();

    return Convert.ToBase64String(asciiCredentials);
}
```

**Client config file:**

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISettings" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://MACHINE_IP_ADDR:8045/MyService/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISettings" contract="SettingsServiceReference.ISettings"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_ISettings" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Server config file:**

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ValidatorServiceBehaviour"
               name="WCFServiceLibrary.SettingsService">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="ValidatorBinding"
                  contract="WCFServiceLibrary.ISettings"  />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8045/MyService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ValidatorServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceDebug httpsHelpPageEnabled="true"
                        includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                    customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="UserValidator.Validator, UserValidator" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ValidatorBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
          </security>
        </binding>

      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The Validator is just a standard `UserNamePasswordValidator`.

Comment: If anyone knows of a better way to do this, without encoding the username/password and setting the header manually please add your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

**Client config file:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_ITestService">
              <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://test/TestService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_ITestService"
            contract="ITestService" name="BasicHttpsBinding_ITestService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Client code:**

```
 var client = new TestServiceClient("BasicHttpsBinding_ITestService");
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "User name";
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```